# How to link from a Sphinx document into a CHM file?

Tags: python-sphinx, chm

How can I link from a Sphinx document into a CHM file?

It seems that I could link from one chm file into another using a syntax like

```html
<a href="ms-its:path+filename.chm::/pagename.htm">
```

Is it possible to transfer this into Sphinx commands?

Comment: Do you want to use build command e.g. `make html` and link from a HTML topic to a special topic `pagename.htm` of `filename.chm`? OR do you want to use `make htmlhelp` and link from the resulting Compiled Help Module (CHM file) to a special topic `pagename.htm` in another `filename.chm`?

Comment: In the end, I want to do both: I want to have a concept which would allow to make full use of chm files in Sphinx, that is to use them in all possible outputs. At the moment, I'd be happy if I would get one of them working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, opening a topic compiled into a CHM is possible with Microsoft Internet Explorer only (!) by adding following code in a HTML file:

```html
<p>Sample of CHM link to a topic in a compiled help file that is stored on a local computer</p>
<!-- To link to a topic in a compiled help file that is stored on a local computer, create a link using the following syntax:  -->
<A HREF="ms-its:D:\UserData-Sphinx\CHM-example.chm::/garden/garden.htm">Link to Garden topic here</a>
```

I think, the `reStructuredText` parser cannot transfer these special kind of link from the source (reST).

But you can use the `Replacement Text` like shown below. Please note, the backslash is used twice:

```
================
Replacement Text
================

I recommend you try |HTMLHelp|_ and continue compiling help in CHM file format.

.. |HTMLHelp| replace:: CHM, *the* best help format around
.. _HTMLHelp: ms-its:D:\\UserData-Sphinx\\CHM-example.chm::/garden/garden.htm
```

The "replace" directive is used to indicate replacement text for a substitution reference. It may be used within substitution definitions only.

**The resulting HTML file view:**

[image]

**The compiled help CHM:**

[image]

**The topic `garden.htm` is shown in the Help Viewer's topic pane after the link iswas clicked:**

[image]

You may download the above used `CHM-example.chm` file from my HTMLHelp (HH) info site [see download section](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh.htm) or download [CHM](http://www.help-info.de/files_download/CHM-example.chm).

Please note, to open this CHM file right-click the saved file, click Properties, and then click Unblock.

Comment: Looks good, though it would be great to also have a firefox solution.